# Creating an array with its name as a user input Python then displaying it with the name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make it so users can create text art and name then to their liking and then when they go onto the Art list they can see their art's name and show it. At the moment I have this:

```
#
#Text Art Thing
#15/05/2015
#By Dom

while True:
    UserInput = input("##################################################\n1 -       Create new art\n2 - Manage saved art\n3 - Watch a slideshow of all the     art\n##################################################\n\n")

    Art = []

    def NewArt():
        stop = False
        x = input("What would you like to call your art?  ")
        vars()[x] = []
        ln = 1
        while stop == False :
            inputln = input("" + str(ln) + ")  ")
            if inputln == "end" :
                stop = True
                print("You have exited the editor. Your art is shown below!\n##################################################\n")
                print("\n".join(vars()[x]))
                print("\n##################################################\n")
                Art.append(vars()[x])
            ln += 1
            vars()[x].append(inputln)





    if UserInput == "1" :
        print("Loading...")
        NewArt()
    if UserInput == "2" :
        print("Loading...")
        SavedArt()
    if UserInput == "3" :
        print("Loading...")
        SlideArt()
```

This can create multiple art fine but I only get this then I type in art:
`[['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'end']]`
The name does not show typing Cat only gets a error.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Just use a dict, key as input string list as  value

Comment: Sorry new to python :/ could you explain?

Comment: create a dict `names = {}`, then `names[x] = []`, in the loop `names[x].append(whatever)`

Comment: Canonical duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python

Comment: Just by the way here, but you don't need to begin a string concatenation with an empty string.

Comment: You can also do `while True` and `if inputln == "end" ...break`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all art in a Python dict, relating each "image" (ASCII art string) to a name.

Example:

```
art = {}

# ...

x = input("What would you like to call your art?  ")
art[x] = []

while stop == False :

# ...

art[x].append(inputln)
```

Comment: This works okay however it removes my previous array inside the dict when I create a new one.

Comment: @Dom `art = {}` should be before the `while True:` statement. As a "global"